# Using async to call an associated json file when link clicked

Tags: javascript, json, async.js

I have a project where I have to use json files to make a friend list and then their name link to the profile. I have gotten to the point where clicking the friend's tab brings up the friends.json file, but I can't figure out how to use async to call the profile. The profiles are separate json files that go with each friend (ex. 1.json, 2.json, etc.).

I have an event for the link click and that's where I've been stuck at. I'm really new to javascript and I understand this using PHP but not javascript. I also can't change the html or json files, just the javascript.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Clark",
    "lastName": "Kent"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "lastName": "Anne"
}]
```

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    const loadDataLink = document.querySelector('.friends a');
    const display = document.querySelector('.content');
    let appData=[];
    let friendList = ``;

    fetch('friends/friends.json').then
    (response => response.json()).then
    (data =>{
      appData =  [...data]
      buildMarkup() 

  }) 

  function buildMarkup(){
    let listItem = ``;
     appData.forEach(friend=>{
     listItem += `<li class="friend">${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}</li>`
     })
    const list = `<ul>${listItem}</ul>`
    let fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(list)
    friendList = fragment.querySelector('ul');
    const links = friendList.querySelectorAll('li');
    links.forEach((link, index)=>{
        link.dataset.index = index;
        link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            fetch('friends/.json');
          console.log(e.target.dataset.index)
          display.innerHTML = ""
        }) 
    })   
  }

  loadDataLink.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    display.innerHTML= ""
     display.appendChild(friendList);
  })   

})
```

Even if you just have tips on async I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code your problem has nothing to do with async. The way you use fetch does not use async functions. Async functions allow you to write code that relies less on callbacks. You could read up on [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

However, to fix your code you probably just have to do the same for the friends' json file as you did for the friend list. You could:

- Put the id of a friend in the dataset of the respective list item:

```
appData.forEach(friend=>{
     listItem += `<li class="friend" data-id="${friend.id}">
               ${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}</li>`
     })
```

- Use fetch as you did for your friends list:

```
link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    fetch(`friends/${e.target.dataset.id}.json`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( (data) => {
           buildFriendMarkup(data);
        });
    display.innerHTML = ""
})
```

- Define `buildFriendMarkup` to set up the markup like you did with `buildMarkup` for the friends list

If this isn't what you are looking for you need to be more precise in describing your problem and the errors) you run into.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The way I used fetch was from what I was shown in class so that was probably my problem. I did try "fetch(`friends/${e.target.dataset.id}.json`)" but forgot the ` ` when I did...Thank you so much, I'll let you know if it works.